# What is the best windows tool to capture HTTP traffic?

Tags: windows

When you want to capture browser traffic or general windows HTTP traffic what tool do you use?

Comment: Another helpful "not constructive" question, viewd 26,000 times.  Thanks a lot voretaq7!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Fiddler, hands down!
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Will Fiddler intercept requests made to localhost?

Comment: Yes, Fiddler can also capture localhost traffic.

Comment: couldn't get it to work, it just says fiddler failed to decrypt https, and the website just loads till infinty

Answer (score 37):

Wireshark.  Gets HTTP and anything else you want to look at (DNS, usually).

Comment: +1 Wireshark will get anything that's going through the net card.

Comment: While Wireshark will capture anything, Fiddler is specialized in looking at HTTP traffic. If you're going to look at HTTP / browser traffic, I'd definitely use Fiddler over Wireshark.

Comment: +1. A little known feature is that Wireshark is also capable of decrypting SSL-traffic if you have the receiver's private certificate. Extremely useful imo!

Answer (score 3):

General HTTP traffic:

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (free)

Internet Explorer and Firefox traffic:

[HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/) (crippleware & pay)

Answer (score 2):

Recommend Fiddler and [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) [[Mark. Rasmussen](https://serverfault.com/users/24/mark-s-rasmussen) above], and another GUI http(s) capture that runs on MS Windows and 'other' systems.

> [WebScarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project)

Looks to have the same feature/functionality as Fiddler2, with the addition that it can run on non MS platforms (could be useful for some.)

The Sales Pitch?

> WebScarab is a framework for analysing applications that communicate using the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. WebScarab has several modes of operation, implemented by a number of plugins. In its most common usage, WebScarab operates as an intercepting proxy, allowing the operator to review and modify requests created by the browser before they are sent to the server, and to review and modify responses returned from the server before they are received by the browser. WebScarab is able to intercept both HTTP and HTTPS communication. The operator can also review the conversations (requests and responses) that have passed through WebScarab

Some of the basic functionality of value to web developers, security reviews, in WebScarab include: (from their website)

- Fragments - extracts Scripts and HTML comments
  from HTML pages as they are seen via
  the proxy, or other plugins
- Proxy - observes traffic between the
  browser and the web server. The
  WebScarab proxy is able to observe
  both HTTP and encrypted HTTPS
  traffic, by negotiating an SSL
  connection between WebScarab and the
  browser instead of simply connecting
  the browser to the server and
  allowing an encrypted stream to pass
  through it. Various proxy plugins
  have also been developed to allow the
  operator to control the requests and
  responses that pass through the
  proxy.
- Manual intercept - allows the user to
  modify HTTP and HTTPS requests and
  responses on the fly, before they
  reach the server or browser.
- Beanshell - allows for the execution
  of arbitrarily complex operations on
  requests and responses. Anything that
  can be expressed in Java can be
  executed.
- Reveal hidden fields - sometimes it
  is easier to modify a hidden field in
  the page itself, rather than
  intercepting the request after it has
  been sent. This plugin simply changes
  all hidden fields found in HTML pages to text fields, making them visible, and editable. 
  Bandwidth simulator - allows the user to emulate a slower network, in order to observe how their website would perform when accessed over, say, a modem.

[OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/), the developers of WebScarab also have a number of other Open Source [Projects](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Project) relevant to reviewing website performance, functionality, security et. al.

Answer (score 1):

[justniffer](http://justniffer.sourceforge.net/) It can capture all http traffic, produce apache log, save content as files, measure response time . etc.

Bye,

Answer (score 0):

[nmap / zenmap](http://nmap.org) from [insecure.org](http://insecure.org)

Answer (score 0):

i link using packetyzer for capturing.

its free and it has a easy to use gui.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/packetyzer/

Answer (score 0):

There is little know but rather good Microsoft product for this:

[Microsoft Visual Roundtrip Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=119f3477-dced-41e3-a0e7-d8b5cae893a3&displaylang=en)

It's built on top of Microsoft's Netmon and provides an insane amount of detail. It shows http traffic, including all the packet transfer details and any related DNS requested performed. It also has a go at giving you advice on the results.

Oh did I mention that it's free?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fiddler2 is very handy. Took me a minute to find out that you can use ipv4.fiddler:/ instead of localhost:/
The tool is fast and stable on the first glimpse

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this [HTTP post or Get tool](http://soft-net.net/SendHTTPTool.aspx) (free tool)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this [iehttptools](http://www.neatsoft.net)

Comment: Using a link is cool, but still write the essential parts of the link please.